# Is there a way to make all my \gls{} links italic

Tags: glossaries, italic

I'm using the glossaries package to define a glossary. However, I would like all \gls{} references to appear in italic. Is there any way to do this without adding \it everywhere?

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) and thank you for the question. Could you please add your (minimal working) example starting with `\documentclass...` and ending with `...\end{document}` to the post? It would help solvers tremendously when they try to solve it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Redefine `\glstextformat`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{sample}{name={sample},description={an example}}

\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}

\begin{document}

\gls{sample}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This creates an unusual look, where italicized parentheses may surround a non-italicized acronym. Can anyone recommend a way to either italicize the acronym too, or de-italicize the parentheses?

Comment: @barnhillec Try redefining `\acronymfont` to make the acronym italicized. It depends on whether you're using one of the acronym styles (using `\setacronymstyle`). It might be worth asking a separate question if you want regular entries formatted differently to acronyms.

Comment: Actually, it looks as though the linked question [Different formatting for acronyms and glossary entries](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303888/different-formatting-for-acronyms-and-glossary-entries?lq=1) might be appropriate.