# Different formatting for acronyms and glossary entries

Tags: glossaries

I'm writing my Master Thesis, and I have both a Glossary and a List of Acronyms.

I use the `glossaries` package.

**I'd like to have a different formatting appearance for the acronyms and the galossary entries.**

- Acronyms : displayed bold in the List (and normal in the text)
- Glossary Entries : displayed in italic, both in the text when they occur, and in the table.

Here is my MWE :

```
\documentclass{book}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage{hyperref}       
\usepackage[toc,acronym,section=section]{glossaries} 

\makeglossaries
\glsenableentrycount

% GLOSSARY
\newglossaryentry{glscard}{
    name=cardinality,
    description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

% ACRONYMS
\newacronym{pc}{PC}{Personal Computer}   
\newacronym{mesh}{MSH}{Mesh Secant Header}      

% Custom Glossary Style
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}
     {\end{longtable}}%
      \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
      \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} &
      \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space 
      \ifnum\glsentryprevcount{##1}=1\relax
        page
      \else
        pages
      \fi
      ##2\tabularnewline
     }%
 }
% End custom Glossary Style
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{document} 


\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main, style=mylong]
\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=acronym, style=mylong]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}

\gls{pc}; \gls{pc}; \gls{glscard}; \newpage 
\gls{mesh}

\end{document}
```

I tried these commands :

- `\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}`, from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13163/28926) to display in bold in the list, but it applies on **both** lists, the acronyms and the glossary.
- `\renewcommand{\glstextformat}[1]{\textit{#1}}` from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/168690/28926) to display them in italic in the text, but again, it applies for both the acronyms and the glossary entries.

Does somebody have an idea on how fix the mix ??

**EDIT :** I added the custom glossary style (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300270/28926)) for controlling how they appear in the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

[image]

If yes, this can be achieved with `\defglsentryfmt[type]{...}`, whereas the `type` argument means the glossary type (acronym, main glossary, etc.) and the mandatory argument is used for the typesetting command.

For me information on this, see section 6.3 of the `glossaries-user` manual.

```
\documentclass{book}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage{hyperref}       
\usepackage[toc,acronym,section=section]{glossaries} 



\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{\textit{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}}
\defglsentryfmt[main]{\textbf{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}}
\makeglossaries
\glsenableentrycount

% GLOSSARY
\newglossaryentry{glscard}{
    name=cardinality,
    description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

% ACRONYMS
\newacronym{pc}{PC}{Personal Computer}   
\newacronym{mesh}{MSH}{Mesh Secant Header}      

\renewcommand{\acronymfont}[1]{\textit{#1}}



\setglossarystyle{list}    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{document} 


\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main]
\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=acronym]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}

\gls{pc}; \gls{pc}; \gls{glscard}; \newpage 
\gls{mesh}

\end{document}
```

**Update**

With special glossary style for italic glossary entries in the `glossary` as well.

```
\documentclass{book}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage{hyperref}       
\usepackage[toc,acronym,section=section]{glossaries} 


\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{\textbf{\glsgenacfmt}}
\defglsentryfmt[main]{\textit{\glsgenentryfmt}}


\makeglossaries
\glsenableentrycount

% GLOSSARY
\newglossaryentry{glscard}{
    name=cardinality,
    description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

% ACRONYMS
\newacronym{pc}{PC}{Personal Computer}   
\newacronym{mesh}{MSH}{Mesh Secant Header}      


\newglossarystyle{mylist}{%
  \setglossarystyle{list}
  \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
  \item[\normalfont\itshape \glsentryitem{##1}%  
    \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}]
    \glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2}%
}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{document} 


\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main,style=mylist]
\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=acronym,style=list]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}

\gls{pc}; \gls{pc}; \gls{glscard}; \newpage 
\gls{mesh}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Partly. It's what I want for the glossary (in italic), but the bold has to come only in the list of  acronyms, not in the text. Thanks for the quick reply, though !

Comment: @EisenHeim: Ok, I'll try to update

Comment: @EisenHeim: The display of gls - entries in the text and the glossary itself is treated by different commands, i.e. the glossary style for the later.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Try adding `\Gls{glscard}` or `\glspl{pc}` or `\glsdisp{pc}{custom text}` to your example ;-) You've redefined it so that the value of the `text` field is only ever used regardless of the invoking command. Try `\defglsentryfmt[acronym]{\textit{\glsgenacfmt}}` and `\defglsentryfmt[main]{\textbf{\glsgenentryfmt}}` instead.

Comment: @Christian Hupfer : I'll update my post with the custom style I use , from [there](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/300270/28926).

Comment: @EisenHeim: See the update, please

Answer (score 2):

There's a simpler method if you use the [`glossaries-extra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package. This provides an extra key `category` (independent of `type`) which can be used to customized different types of terms.

If you don't specify `category`, it defaults to `general` for `\newglossaryentry`, `abbreviation` for `\newabbreviation` and `acronym` for `\newacronym`.

Attributes for a given category are set using `\glssetcategoryattribute`. The `textformat` attribute governs the way terms are formatted in the text. So to make all terms with `category=general` appear in italics:

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{textformat}{emph}
```

This overrides `\glstextformat` for entries with this category attribute.

The `glossnamefont` attribute governs the formatting of the name in the description. It's used internally by `\glossentryname` and overrides the default `\glsnamefont`. So to make all terms with `category=general` have the name appear in italics in the glossary:

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossnamefont}{emph}
```

Similarly for bold terms with `category=acronym`:

```
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossnamefont}{textbf}
```

Incidentally, `glossaries-extra` also has a simpler method of inserting "page"/"pages" at the start of the location list:

```
\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{page~}{pages~}
```

(Using entry counting isn't reliable as you may only use an entry on a single page, but if you use it multiple times on that page, the count will be greater than 1 so you'll end up with "pages" for a single location.)

The `toc` and `nopostdot` package options are implemented by default with `glossaries-extra`.

Complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}    

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        

\usepackage{hyperref}       
\usepackage[acronym,section=section]{glossaries-extra} 

\makeglossaries

\GlsXtrEnablePreLocationTag{page~}{pages~}

\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{textformat}{emph}
\glssetcategoryattribute{general}{glossnamefont}{emph}
\glssetcategoryattribute{acronym}{glossnamefont}{textbf}

% GLOSSARY
\newglossaryentry{glscard}{
    name=cardinality,
    description={The number of elements in the specified set}}

% ACRONYMS
\newacronym{pc}{PC}{Personal Computer}   
\newacronym{mesh}{MSH}{Mesh Secant Header}      

% Custom Glossary Style
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{%
  \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}[l]{@{}p{\dimexpr 2cm-\tabcolsep}p{0.8\hsize}}}
     {\end{longtable}}%
 }
% End custom Glossary Style
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\begin{document} 


\printglossary[toctitle=Lexique,type=main, style=mylong]
\printglossary[toctitle=Acronyms,type=acronym, style=mylong]

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{ab}

\gls{pc}; \gls{pc}; \gls{glscard}; \newpage 
\gls{mesh}

\end{document}
```

First page:

[image: image of glossary and list of abbreviations]

Document text (page 3):

[image: PC; PC; cardinality;]

(page 4)

[image: MSH]